# :hover not working on div, working on other parts of page

Tags: html, css

My hover class is not working on my button div however it is working on other parts of my webpage including ones using the absolute position.

```css
.desbutton {
  margin-left: 25px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 113px;
  background-color: #4A6D81;
  border-radius: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.desbutton:hover {
  background-color: #80999E;
}
```

```html
<div class="desbutton">
  <p class="butText">READ MORE</p>
</div>
```

[Jsfiddle with full src](https://jsfiddle.net/96kp9gcj/)

Comment: You have problem with `.designCard` and `z-index: -1`. Because of this hover is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check : why do you have in your `.designCard` attr `z-index: -1`. This causes that your body element is `higher` then your card and because of this your hover is never "called"